# Kind of base module in Angular

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, config, radix

I've an angular module, which have some configuration code like:

```
angular.module('qrApp').config(['$httpProvider', '$sceDelegateProvider', function ($httpProvider, $sceDelegateProvider) {
    // configuring providers
}]);

qrApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    // custom directive here
}]);
```

And now i need another new module, that would have same configuration and directive setup, what is the best way not to duplicate code but have some kind of "base" module so both could inherit from it and so have same setup. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place common code in separate module and add that module to dependency list of your modules

```
//common.js
angular.module('common', []).config(...).directive(...);
```

and then use it

```
angular.module('qrApp', ['common']);
```

Comment: Thanks! Simple and clear solution! Could you pls share some link on topic to read about to better understand what is happened when i do this way?